# How to make `dotnet-format` ignoring certain directory?

Tags: c#, formatting, dotnet-format

I have the following lines defined in my `.editorconfig` file:

```
# Ignore paths
[Assets/NRSDK/*]

[Assets/VLCUnity/*]

generated_code = true
```

But they are ineffective, every time I run `dotnet-format` it still format everything under them. Is it feature broken? What can be done to make it honoured?

Comment: `[Assets/NRSDK/*]` and `[Assets/VLCUnity/*]` are separate section headers. You need to use `[{Assets/NRSDK/*,Assets/VLCUnity/*}]` as your section header or repeat the name/value pair for both sections.

Comment: `generated_code` is used by the code analyzers but from the documentation it is not clear if `dotnet format` honors the `generated_code` value for all sub-commands.

Comment: Have you tried `dotnet format --exclude Assets/NRSDK Assets/VLCUnity`?

Comment: @JonathanDodds yes, and it only excludes "Assets/NRSDK", the other was ignored as an irrelevant argument

Comment: The documentation says "A space-separated list of relative file or folder paths to exclude from formatting." Do you try variants like `dotnet format --exclude "Assets/NRSDK Assets/VLCUnity"` or `dotnet format --exclude Assets/NRSDK --exclude Assets/VLCUnity`?

Comment: @JonathanDodds Thanks a lot `dotnet format --exclude Assets/NRSDK --exclude Assets/VLCUnity` does work. Would you like to write an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the given `.editorconfig` content, `[Assets/NRSDK/*]` and `[Assets/VLCUnity/*]` are separate section headers. They don't combine. Use `[{Assets/NRSDK/*,Assets/VLCUnity/*}]` as the section header or duplicate the name/value pairs for both sections.

It appears that `generated_code = true`, while used by code analyzers, may not be recognized or honored by `dotnet format`. (Maybe that should be a [feature request](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/new/choose).)

The `format` subcommand has an `--exclude` switch. The switch can appear multiple times in the same command line.

The following should work:

```
dotnet format --exclude Assets/NRSDK --exclude Assets/VLCUnity
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `--exclude` option, this is an example from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-format#options)

```
dotnet format --include ./src/ ./tests/ --exclude ./src/submodule-a/
```

Comment: What if I need to exclude multiple directories?